# How to test a button click in enzyme test if there is no proptypes associated with the component

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

I'm implementing an enzyme test script for a ReactJs application. Here I have a login component to be tested which is not using any proptypes on either onClick or onSubmit functions. I have tried so many methods and couldn't find a solution yet. The following is the submit part

```
       {(function() {
           if (this.state.loading) {  // set this state as false to go to else conditioin.
           return <button className="button disabled" type="button"><i className="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-fw margin-bottom"></i></button>;
                                   } 
           else {
           return <button className="button" type="button" onClick={this.login}>Continue</button>;
                 }
       }.bind(this))()}
```

Here I have tried various method to mock the button and always showing the disabled button for the command
 **const button = wrapper.find('button');
 console.log(button.simulate('click').debug());**

And **expect(spy.calledOnce).to.be.true** couldn't use here to check whether it has happened or not. Is there any solution to make this button click happen.